# Smtp Server external to external

Tags: email, smtp, email-server, spam

I have hMailServer set up on my windows server 2008 machine.

I just started noticing in the logs that there are a lot of entries
related to people trying to send external to external mails (obv spam?)
through my machine.

I've not set the server to allow ext 2 ext mail delivery. It did look like
it was all coming from one ip range but now it's from all over - is there
anything I can do to stop this?

The ip ranges seem to be in the same range but it's only the first byte that's the same - it comes from 2 ranges by the looks of it - i'm not at my server but it looked like 114.*.*.* and 214.*.*.*

Might be wrong with those but you get my meaning. I was looking at using IP Security Manager to stop those IPs even hitting the mail server

is that advisable? being that they are such huge ranges?

If it is advisable - how do you specify a range in the ip security snap in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have mail incoming on these servers blocking, IP ranges that big is not a good idea.

The attempts should not burn much bandwidth as they should be blocked before the message is actually transmitted.

Consider using spamhaus.org blacklist,  that should cut out most of these attempts.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly; if you’re not allowing it on your side, then I wouldn't worry too much about it.  Being a corporate environment, we see this all the time.  The best advice I could give you for this issue is to keep current with updates.  If you block a range of IPs and one of those happens to be important down the road, you might hurt yourself more then just blocking an annoyance.

Comment: this is what I was thinking. Will all these attempts burn the bandwidth? the log file got to be quite a few Mb - probably 1mb p/min

Comment: We use exchange for our email, and as such our log files tend to be large as well.  One idea that may help you as well is to use a blacklisting service.  Now, from what I remember back when I used hMail, you could specify where you wanted the server to lookup blacklist information.  Another idea as well is you could report the IP’s to the ISPs abuse department.  For the other part of your question, the only way to know is to put some monitoring tools in place, but I wouldn’t think it would be burning too much.

Comment: I enabled spamhause and i'm looking into spamassasin - the logs were 1Gb in about 14 hours!